# UITableView inside the UIScrollView for horizontal scrolling does not work as expected

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I  use a table view which has got the cells with varied set of information and which can not be contained with in the frame of the tableView. So I do need to have a horizontal scrolling capacity in the table view.

Since horizontal scrolling is not possible with tableview,I planned to use a scrollView with horizontal scroll. I added the tableView on top of the scrollView.

The problem I face is irrespective of the content size property of the scrollview, the scrollview never scrolls beyond the contentOffset value X of 256-320 pixels.

I am planning to achieve the effect as it is in the below screen shot[image]

Comment: So are you now using a `UIScrollView`?

Comment: Maybe UITableView isn't the way to go. I suggest you use a simple `UIScrollView` and manually populate it with custom `UIViews`.

Comment: yes H2CO3. On top of UIScrollView I add the UITableView

Comment: Some code on how you add the tableview inside the scrollview may be helpful

Comment: I did everything using Interface Builder

Comment: @Krishnan It would be useful to use a UIScrollView only. Scroll views can act strange when you put one on top of the other. Also, consider doing this task from code, because it may need flexibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented the entire functionality using code without using interface builder. It works as expected now. I did not know why it did not work when used with interface builder.

Answer (score 0):

Try two things,

First Set the TableView height as total numberOfRows :

```
tableView.frame.size.y  = numberOfRows * 44;
```

now disable the tableView Scrolling

and set he scrollView contentSize as per your need;

```
scollerView.contentSize = numberOfRowsintableView
```

Surely it will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Set proper ContentSize for ScrollView in ViewDidLoad.

```
scollerView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(Width,Height);
```

Calculate the Width as Per Requirement And Height (you are using Tableview So You can take Height same as View Height)

Then it will Surely Scroll.